# How could I refer typings to be included at runtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

my question (in details) might have duplicates here but I couldn't be able to get answeres since I have spent 3 days searching for it. 
I am new to typescript and want to run a TS project (and not any angular 2 thing in it) using '`npm start`' command. Please have a look at below code:

**My directory structure is**:

[image: My directory structure]

**myClass.ts** (it is inside module directory)

```
export namespace Classes {
    export class NewClass {
        constructor(public msg:string){}
        displayMessage ():string{
            return this.msg;
        }
    };
};
```

**greeter.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title> TypeScript Greeter </title></head>
  <body>
    <script src='greeter.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**greeter.ts**

```
import {Classes} from 'module/myClass';
class Greeter extends Classes.NewClass {
    constructor(public greeting: string) { 
        super('');
    }
    greet() {
        return "<h1>" + this.greeting + "</h1>";
    }
};

var greeter = new Greeter("Hello, world!");
var newClass = new Classes.NewClass("This is my message.");
document.body.innerHTML = greeter.greet() + newClass.displayMessage();
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "greeter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sample TS app",
  "main": "greeter.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && http-server"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "TS"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "sourceMap":  true,
        "module": "commonjs",       
        "outDir": "./out"
    },
    "files": [
        "greeter.ts",
        "module/myClass.ts"
    ]
}
```

**typings.json**

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160928143418"
  }
}
```

**My queries are**:

1. I have included 'dt~node' typings after watching a few tutorials, but is it necessary here in this scenario ?
2. I am from javascript background, so I am not sure how to include the typings files in my project. Do I need to include reference path in greeter.html for typings files or something else. Please specify this.
3. I am unable to make it work as browser console displays this error after running 'npm start' in window's command:

[image: Browser console's error]

Please help if anyone could guide me to resolve my queries. Thank you.

Comment: Add `"typings/index.d.ts"` to the `"files"` in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: @cartant ... I have tried it, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Am I missing some other typings that I should install in order to get 'require'.